# Binary search in functional-style Scala

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, scala

Curious to know how I can improve it, especially the pattern matching part seems a bit repetitive at the moment (lots of `case x if ds(x)`)

```
  def binarySearch(ds: Array[Double], key: Double): Int = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(low: Int, mid: Int, high: Int): Int = {
      mid match {
        case x if ds(x) == key => x
        case x if high <= low => -1
        case x if ds(x) < key => go(mid + 1, (high - mid + 1) / 2  + mid, high)
        case x if ds(x) > key => go(low, (mid - low) / 2 + low, mid - 1)
      }
    }
    ds.size match {
      case 0 => -1
      case _ => go(0, ds.size / 2, ds.size - 1)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `high <= low` part does not involve `x` and could be pulled out of the case. The rest is fine IMHO.

One remark: the `-1` return in the error-case is a bit of a *smell* - why not return `Option[Int]` instead?

And finally: I think you don't need `mid` as an argument - as you guard for `low > high` anyway you can as easily compute it inside your inner function and make the calls a bit more readable (only low and high)

### Could look like this

```
  type Index = Int

  def binarySearch(ds: Array[Double], key: Double): Option[Index] = {
      @tailrec
      def go(lo: Index, hi: Index): Option[Index] = {
        if (lo > hi)
          None
        else {
          val mid: Index = lo + (hi - lo) / 2
          ds(mid) match {
            case mv if (mv == key) => Some(mid)
            case mv if (mv <= key) => go(mid + 1, hi)
            case _ => go(lo, mid - 1)
          }
        }
      }
      go(0, ds.size - 1)
  }
```

Comment: You introduced a serious bug by changing the code from `(high - mid + 1) / 2  + mid` to `mid = (lo + hi) / 2` - the first one is safe from overflow, the later isn't. The correct code is `lo + (hi - lo) / 2`.

Comment: yes thank you for pointing this out - big blunder there on my part!

Comment: Why use pattern matching on `ds(mid)` instead of just plain if/else if/else?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh because you would get two nested `if`s which most people see as ugly and in my opinion the match is just more readable